# Find who invoked AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have Lambda function written in Python 3.7.

This Lambda function is invoked by some users through AWS CLI using:

```
  aws lambda invoke --function-name stXXX-XXX out --log-type Tail
```

I want to capture who invoked my Lambda function through AWS CLI in my code.

As there any way I can find who invoke my Lambda function in python boto3 code?

Comment: Can you please tell us _why_ you want this information? That is, what is the _actual_ goal you are wanting to achieve? We might then be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: @John This Lambda starts one EC2 server.But due to the general role other guys also in organization would have access to invoke this Lambda and start EC2.So i want to validate inside my lambda which user invoked it and if its from authorize list then only start Ec2.

Comment: There are better, high-level options here such as Service Catalog (create templates for the runtime environments you want users to be able to launch and then manage their access via IAM), or even building an API in front of the Lambda and having your users authenticate to use the API.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Generally for that you would have to enable [logging data event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html) in CloudTrail:

- [Logging AWS Lambda API calls with AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)

By default logging of lambda invocations is disabled as it can lead to a lot of logs.

The log event [contains information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html#understanding-service-name-entries) about what IAM user or role invoked the function. For example:

```
      "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "A1B2C3D4E5F6G7EXAMPLE",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:user/myUserName",
        "accountId": "999999999999",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "userName": "myUserName"
      },
```

Comment: @AWS_Beginner Unfortunately, you can't do this directly. Wound need to parse the logs from S3 or CloudWatch Logs. This can be done using Athena (S3) for instance.

Comment: In cloudwatchLogs i am not getting this info.I printed event and context of lambda but this info was not present.

Comment: This answer mentions CloudTrail, not CloudWatch--they are different and give different things.  CloudTrail is where you'll want to look.

Comment: @AWS_Beginner This information you are after is only available through CloudTrial.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that your situation is:

- You have an AWS Lambda function that Starts an Amazon EC2 instance
- You want the Lambda function to detect *who* has made the request and then confirm that they are on an authorization list before starting the Amazon EC2 instance

Unfortunately, information about 'who' invoked the Lambda function (or, more specifically, which IAM entity invoked it) is not available.

The [AWS Lambda context object in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) does not provide this information to the Lambda function.

A "more correct" way would be to **control the IAM permissions that determine who can invoke this Lambda function**. Only correctly authorized persons should have permission to call `lambda:Invoke` on this function. Similarly, it is important to limit who can use `iam:PassRole` on the IAM Role used by this function, since it has permissions to start the EC2 instance and it could be used on other functions unless `PassRole` is restricted.

Comment: There is a function policy that can help restrict who can call the lambda. This will be a preventative control rather than detective, hence the Lambda can always assume only authorized IAM roles invoked it.